# CSS border-radius changes the background corners

Tags: css

I want to put a circle on each element on `hover` like what you can see here for divs 4 and 5. The problem happens when a div has a background color already (e.g. div 6, 7 and 8) and hovering over it, makes the corners white instead of the background color it had before.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.child:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.myClass {
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
}

.myClass:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">4</span>
  <span class="child">5</span>
  <span class="child myClass">6</span>
  <span class="child myClass">7</span>
  <span class="child myClass">8</span>
</div>
```

I want it to look like the red hovering circle is on top of the gray div, without having any white corners. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: hint: it's not white but transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the circle with a `background-image`

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.child:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
}

.myClass {
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
}

.myClass:hover {
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-side, red 99%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">4</span>
  <span class="child">5</span>
  <span class="child myClass">6</span>
  <span class="child myClass">7</span>
  <span class="child myClass">8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of doing it by adding a pseudo `::before` element and making it's background gray.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.child:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.myClass {
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  position: relative;
}

.myClass:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.myClass:hover::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">4</span>
  <span class="child">5</span>
  <span class="child myClass">6</span>
  <span class="child myClass">7</span>
  <span class="child myClass">8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo element for your circle:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.myClass {
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
}

.myClass:hover:after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">4</span>
  <span class="child">5</span>
  <span class="child myClass">6</span>
  <span class="child myClass">7</span>
  <span class="child myClass">8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the div is transparent, so you could just put the color to the parent div?

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #a1a1a1;
}

.child {
  padding: 2rem;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.child:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #a1a1a1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.myClass {
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
}
 
.myClass:hover{
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">4</span>
    <span class="child">5</span>
    <span class="child myClass">6</span>
    <span class="child myClass">7</span>
    <span class="child myClass">8</span>
  </div>
```